# Laravel Botman Studio

Tags: laravel-5

I've installed botman studio on my existing laravel project to create a chat bot. The chatbot works. However, im looking for complex conversations where user can ask chatbot "What is Example" and Chat box searches from the database table and answers back.

I do not find any tutorial or links that can help me get started. Does anyone know how to do this? A simple example could help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a possible implementation to tipical questions where you listen for the last keyword, so you could configure bot to listen *What is* + `*keyword_to_search*`

```
$botman->hears('What is (^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$)', function ($bot, $keyword) {
    $answer = \App\Answer::where('keyword', 'LIKE', $keyword)->get();
    $bot->reply('Answer: '.$answer);
});
```

This is extremly simple, you could start chat with --help and list all keywoards that a user can ask for example, it would be kinda cool I guess.

If you would like to implement more complex stuff you could try to learn about Natural Language Processing(NPL), you can read more about it on [botman docs](https://botman.io/2.0/nlp).